# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de los data-variableX en una función javascript para mostrarlo a una modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap

Tengo un enlace en donde almaceno datos para enviarlos a una modal usando `data-variable`, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-id='<%:id%>' data-nombre='<%: nombre %>' class="datos_edit" onclick="enviaDatosEdit();">Editar</a>
```

Y recibo los datos con una función de jQuery a través del nombre de la clase `datos_edit`:

```
$('.datos_edit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ID = $(this).data('id');
    Nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
});
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede recibir los datos en una función JavaScript? Como por ejemplo `enviaDatosEdit()` sin estar pasándole parámetros:

```
enviaDatosEdit('<%:id%>', '<%: nombre %>');">
```

Sino que, utilizar los `data-id`, `data-nombre` en la función `enviaDatosEdit()`, en el cual, que me quedase algo como:

```
function enviaDatosEdit(){
    e.preventDefault();
    ID = $(this).data('id');
    Nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
}
```

Comment: no se entiende bien la pregunta, parece que la respuesta esta ahi...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si, puedes. Si bien no lo encuentro lo mas elegante, tienes estas dos soluciones.

Una es:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-id='<%:id%>' data-nombre='<%: nombre %>' class="datos_edit" onclick="enviaDatosEdit.call(this);">Editar</a>
```

Con esa solución lo que haces es cambiarle el contexto this a `enviaDatosEdit`, entonces `this` en `enviaDatosEdit` cuando se llamada de esa forma (`call`) sera el elemento `a`, si `enviaDatosEdit` es llamada sin `call`, su contexto (`this`) será `window`.

La siguiente seria:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-id='<%:id%>' data-nombre='<%: nombre %>' class="datos_edit" onclick="enviaDatosEdit(this);">Editar</a>

function enviaDatosEdit(elem) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    ID = $(elem).data('id');
    Nombre = $(elem).data('nombre');
}
```

La primera, si bien se entiende, puede llevar a confusión a quien vea ese codigo.
Ah, otra cosa, los atributos debes (`data-`) sacarlos usando `attr`(al menos en Jquery) y las propiedades con prop(id,class,disabled,etc-las 'nativas'-)

Finalmente yo usaría esto si estas usando jquery, así:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-id='<%:id%>' data-nombre='<%: nombre %>' class="datos_edit">Editar</a>


$('.datos_edit').on('click', enviaDatosEdit);

function enviaDatosEdit(event)
{
    //  this aqui es el contexto que le da jquery al invocar al click, osea this es el elemento 'a'
    var $this=$(this); 
    //  tambien si te complican los contextos,
    //  te serviria  usa var $this=$(event.target); target aqui es el elemnto que 
    //  invoco al evento 
    // introducir el código aquí
    event.preventDefault();
    ID = $this.attr('data-id');
    Nombre = $this.attr('data-nombre');
}
```

Recuerda siempre cachear tus elementos Jquery y luego hacer referencia a esa variable cacheada:

```
var $elem=$("#tuid");
```

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te he entendido bien, así que igual no contesto a lo que preguntas...

No tienes por qué crear una nueva función `callback` como parámetro de `click`, podrías pasarle una que ya tuvieses definida.

```
function enviaDatosEdit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ID = $(this).data('id');
    Nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
}

$('.datos_edit').click(enviaDatosEdit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sin pasar parámetros no sería posible hacer lo que quieres hacer, porque en ese caso el `this` de la función no será el elemento que ha llamado a la función sino que se inicializaría por defecto al objeto global y sería `window`.

Una cosa que podrías hacer para crear una función genérica sería pasar el objeto en el que se origina la acción como parámetro usando `this` (en la llamada):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-id='<%:id%>' data-nombre='<%: nombre %>' class="datos_edit" onclick="enviaDatosEdit(this);">Editar</a>

...

function enviaDatosEdit(obj){
    e.preventDefault();
    ID = $(obj).data('id');
    Nombre = $(obj).data('nombre');
}
```